# String validation function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a nice util function to validate strings. Conditions are:

1. Cannot be `typeof "undefined"`
2. Cannot be `null`
3. Must be a string i.e. not a number, object, array, etc.
4. Must have at least one character in it. So a string with value of `''` would be invalid.

I found some pointers on this that suggest using `RegEx` is the way to do it but the following is not working when I give it a numeric value.

Here's what I have so far:

```
const isValidString = (str1) => {

   if(typeof str1 === "undefined" || str1 === null) return false;

   const validRegEx = /^[^\\\/&]*$/;
   if(str1.match(validRegEx)) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

As I said, if send `const str1 = 3;` to this function, I get an error that reads:

> "TypeError: badString.match is not a function

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (str1 != null)` will coerce the `str1` value, and will check both against `null` and `undefined`.

EDIT: ignore this part (Also, you don't need to use a regex to check if there's at least one character. You can use the string `length`. `str1.length` will evaluate to a `false`y value if it's 0, otherwise it will evaluate to a `true`thy value.) You need a strict `boolean` value, so it should be `str1.length > 0`.

```
function isValidString(str1) {
  return str1 != null && typeof str1 === "string" && str1.length > 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice and terse!

Comment: @Sam Glad it helped! Thanks!

Comment: If you want the function to strictly return a boolean, you'll need to expand `str1.length` to `str1.length > 0`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts actually you're right... I'm editing it.. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You beat me to it. I was just posting this: `return str1 != null && typeof str1 === "string" && str1.length > 0;` will always return `true` or `false`

Comment: should be `str1.trim().length > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a `typeof str1 === 'string'` as shown below

```
if(typeof str1 === 'string' && str1.match(validRegEx)) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the match method is only available on strings, and you are attempting to call it on a number.

I would suggest re-writing the function to ensure that the argument is a string, rather than only checking for null or undefined values:

```
const isValidString = str1 => {
  if (!str1 || typeof str1 !== 'string') return false

  const validRegEx = /^[^\\\/&]*$/

  if (str1.match(validRegEx)) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I like this the best. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Convert number to string perform evaluating it

```js
const isValidString = (str1) => {
str1 = str1.toString();
   if(typeof str1 === "undefined" || str1 === null) return false;

   const validRegEx = /^[^\\\/&]*$/;
   if(str1.match(validRegEx)) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}

console.log(isValidString(3))
```

Comment: This is doing the opposite of what I want. If I enter 3 which is a number, I should get a `false`. By converting it `toString()` almost all values become acceptable which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the if with following:

```
if(typeof str1 === "undefined" || str1 === null || typeof str1 !== 'string') return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead, because your regular expression will always be available. Also, [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array (or `null`) which is not well-suited for boolean expressions and may produce unwanted results.

```js
const isValidString = (str1) => {

  if (typeof str1 === "undefined" || str1 === null) return false;
  const validRegEx = /^[^\\\/&]*$/;
  
  if (validRegEx.test(str1)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(isValidString(1));
console.log(isValidString('string'));
```

Note, your regexp is still wrong because it validates the number as `true`. You need to tweak it more.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to djfdev on this one, all I've really done is simplify his answer to be more succinct.

```
const isValidString = str1 => {
    return typeof str1 === 'string' && /^[^\\\/&]*$/.test(str1);
}
```